# Where exactly in the boot process does @reboot in a Cron execute?

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

Where exactly in the boot process does @reboot execute? Would a script starting with `@reboot` in `/etc/crontab` run immediately after the kernel is loaded? Is it after all system services are loaded? Somewhere in between?

Answer (score 1):

It will run asap after the cron daemon has started.